# Basic if conditional in JavaScript return random values

Tags: javascript

I’m new in programming, and I’m doing the Odin Project. I’m having problems with the rock, paper, scissors exercise, where I need to compare the user choice and the machine choice. It’s the `play()` function.

I already try to find the problem, and even look at the code of others (just in that part! not the whole exercise) but I can’t figure out where the problem is.

It just keep returning me random values.

Here is the code:

```js
let userChoice = prompt("Choose your weapon: rock, paper or scissors").toLowerCase();
console.log(userChoice);


function getMachineChoice() {
  let values = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let randomValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
  return randomValue;
}
console.log(getMachineChoice());

let machineChoice = getMachineChoice();

function play(userChoice, machineChoice) {
  if (userChoice === machineChoice) {
    return "Its a tie!";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && machineChoice === "scissors") {
    return "You win!";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && machineChoice === "rock") {
    return "You win!";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissors" && machineChoice === "paper") {
    return "You win!";
  } else {
    return "You lose!";
  }
}
console.log(play(userChoice, machineChoice));
```

Comment: In your getMachineChoice() you return randomValue, but you actually want "rock", "paper" or "scissors", no? :)

Comment: "_It just keep returning me random values_" Yes, that's the purpose of `Math.random()`, it returns a random value _every time_ it's called. Can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: This is a good chance to learn how to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/), where you can step through the code statement by statement, look at the state of variables, and follow your logic through. More [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @meskobalazs - `randomValue` **is** one of those strings: `let randomValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];`

Comment: Note that what you're logging (`console.log(getMachineChoice());`) is not what you're putting in `machineChoice`, because you're calling `getMachineChoice()` again, and it's random. So what you're logging is misleading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to assign the result of `getMachineChoice()` into the variable `machineChoice` first before you call the `console.log`. With that you can get the correct user and machine choice in the console.

(Instead of calling `getMachineChoice()` twice, you should only call it once to generate the result once. Then, assign it to a variable which it can be used for comparison later)

```js
let userChoice = prompt(
  'Choose your weapon: rock, paper or scissors'
).toLowerCase();
console.log(userChoice);

let machineChoice = getMachineChoice();
function getMachineChoice() {
  let values = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  let randomValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
  return randomValue;
}
console.log(machineChoice);

function play(userChoice, machineChoice) {
  if (userChoice === machineChoice) {
    return 'Its a tie!';
  } else if (userChoice === 'rock' && machineChoice === 'scissors') {
    return 'You win!';
  } else if (userChoice === 'paper' && machineChoice === 'rock') {
    return 'You win!';
  } else if (userChoice === 'scissors' && machineChoice === 'paper') {
    return 'You win!';
  } else {
    return 'You lose!';
  }
}
console.log(play(userChoice, machineChoice));
```